# Substrate upgrade to 0.9.26: the trait bound `Event: From<pallet_transaction_payment::Event<Runtime>>` is not satisfied

Tags: polkadot, rust, runtime-upgrade

When trying to upgrade to Substrate v 0.9.26, I see this error:

```
the trait bound `Event: From<pallet_transaction_payment::Event<Runtime>>` is not satisfied
```

In my config I have the following:

```
impl pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    ...
```

As you can see, the trait is implemented. Why is this error getting thrown?

Comment: Which file/line is this error occurring? What version are you upgrading from? How can I replicate this? More info would be appreciated for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include `Event` module part in your `frame_support::construct_runtime!` like so:

```rs
TransactionPayment: pallet_transaction_payment::{Pallet, Storage, Event<T>}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e8a7d161f39db70cb27fdad6c6e215cf493ebc3b/frame/transaction-payment/src/lib.rs#L805

More Info:

- https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/macro.construct_runtime.html